# .nextAll function will not work when used inside a click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to use the .nextAll option in jquery inside a checkbox listed inside modal window.. so the when the user clicks on a link and the modal window opens up, through the function .on("click") , thats when the chexkbox appears and Ive wrote a code inside the click function which alters check prop of the checkbox.

```
$('input[name="Company"],input[name="Country"]').live("click",function(){

if ($(this).is(':checked')){
    alert("s");
      $(this).nextAll('input[name="'+this.name+'Sub"]').prop('checked',true);
} else {
       alert("n");
      $(this).nextAll('input[name="'+this.name+'Sub"]').prop('checked',false);   
}
});

 <input type="checkbox" class="entityCheckboxHeader1" id="entityCheckboxHeader" name="Company">Company
 <input class="modalEntityCompany" id="entity1" type="checkbox" name="CompanySub">Microsoft
 <input class="modalEntityCompany" id="entity2" type="checkbox" name="CompanySub">Apple
<br /> 
<input type="checkbox" class="entityCheckboxHeader2" id="entityCheckboxHeader" name="Country">Country
 <input class="modalEntity" id="entity3" type="checkbox" name="CountrySub">USA
 <input class="modalEntity" id="entity4" type="checkbox" name="CountrySub">UK
```

The program works fine independly when tried in a jsfiddle or inside a new html that we create, bt it will not wrk when it is used inside a click function that I created. what could be causing the conflict?

Note:Im using .live() function for checkbox as it wont even get in to the .nextAll part when .on() is used

DYNAMIC CREATION PART

```
function generateTreeHTML(input) {

var html = '';
var entityNumber = 1;
var color = 663399;
html = "<ul id='tree' class='treeview-black' >";
for ( var m = 0; m < input.length; m++) {


        html+="<li>";

    currentEntity = input[m];

    currentEntityType = currentEntity.entity;

    html += "<span style='font-size:12px;  font-family:Helvetica; font-weight:bold;' id='entityHeader' class='entityHeader"
            + getEntityHeader()
            + "'><input name='" + currentEntityType +"' type='checkbox' id='entityCheckboxHeader' class=\""
            + 'entityCheckboxHeader'
            + getEntityCheckboxHeader()
            + "\" />"
            + currentEntityType
            + "</span><div style='width:15px; height:10px; background-color:#"
            + colorArray[entityNumber]
            + "; float:right; margin-right:50px; margin-top:5px;'></div>";
            html+="<ul>";
    for ( var n = 0; n < currentEntity[currentEntityType].length; n++) {
        html += "<li>";
        var entityName = currentEntity[currentEntityType][n].entity;
        var entityName1 = entityName.split('.').join("");
        entityName1 = entityName1.split('_').join("");
        entityName1 = entityName1.replace(/ /g, "");
        html += "<span><input type='checkbox' key=\"" + entityName
                + "\" mapKey=\"" + currentEntityType
                + "\" categoryNumber=\"" + entityNumber
                + "\" class='modalEntity' id=\"" + 'entity' + getEntityID()
                + "\" name='" + currentEntityType +  "Sub'>" + entityName + "</span>";

        html += "</li>";

    }

    html+="</ul></li>";
    entityNumber = entityNumber + 1;
    html += "<div style='width:200px; border-bottom:1px solid #cccccc; height:1px;'></div>";
}
html += "</ul>";
return html;
    }
```

Comment: Do those alerts appear? ? Regarding your use of `.live()`, did you try putting `.on()` code in a document ready handler or in a script block that appears _after_ the checkboxes it tries to operate on? (Or are the checkboxes added dynamically some time after page load?)

Comment: checkbox is dynamically addded at the time modal window opens, the alerts wont appear when I use .on, alerts appear when using .live() function.

Comment: What do you mean by "works fine independently [but not in] a click function that I created"? Is the code above the click function you are talking about that doesn't work? If it works in a fiddle (and it worked for me: http://jsfiddle.net/ez7cN/) it should work assuming your dynamically added checkboxes follow that structure - can you show the code that does the dynamic creation?

Comment: Wrking fine independently means. I tried this function in a sample html file and added at document load part..

Comment: OK, answer added below. Your dynamically created html is radically different to the html that you initially showed in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`.nextAll()` method](http://api.jquery.com/nextall/) only finds the next *sibling* elements (as stated very clearly in the [doco](http://api.jquery.com/nextall/)). The structure that you are creating dynamically seems to put the related checkboxes each in their own spans inside different li elements - i.e., they are *not* siblings of each other or of the header checkboxes that your click handler belongs to. You can't expect the traversal methods you were using to find the elements to work for different html structures any more than driving directions from my office to my house would work to get to your house.

Try this instead:

```
$('input[name="Company"],input[name="Country"]').live("click",function(){    
   if ($(this).is(':checked')){
      alert("s");
      $('input[name="'+this.name+'Sub"]').prop('checked',true);
   } else {
       alert("n");
      $('input[name="'+this.name+'Sub"]').prop('checked',false);   
   }
});
```

Which can be greatly simplified to:

```
$('input[name="Company"],input[name="Country"]').live("click",function(){    
      $('input[name="'+this.name+'Sub"]').prop('checked',this.checked);    
});
```

Or if you're concerned that there might be other checkboxes of the same name elsewhere in your document you could look just within the same li element that the clicked header box belongs to:

```
$(this).closest('li')
       .find('input[name="'+this.name+'Sub"]').prop('checked',this.checked);
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a class say `checkinput` to checkbox `input[name="Company"] and input[name="Country"]"`

```
$('body').delegate(".checkinput","click",function(){

    if ($(this).is(':checked')){
        alert("s");
          $(this).nextAll('input[name="'+$(this).attr('name')+'Sub"]').prop('checked',true);
    } else {
           alert("n");
          $(this).nextAll('input[name="'+$(this).attr('name')+'Sub"]').prop('checked',false);   
    }
    });
```

Comment: what does $('body') do? this one didnt even produce an alert?